# Combining .split() and .match() results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create an array that contains substrings  of string that passes my regex and substrings. For example:

`['stringpart1', 'match1', 'stringpart2', 'match2', 'stringpart3']`

This is my regex: `new RegExp("<(\/)?" + tag + ".*?>", "g");`

I am using a page source string something along the lines of:

```
"<html>\n
    <meta class='a'/>\n
    <meta class='b'/>\n
    <div>\n
        <p>test</p>\n
    </div>\n
</html>"
```

If I use my page source with `.split(re)`, I am getting a value of

`['<html>\n', undefined, '\n', undefined, '\n', '<div>\n<p>test</p>\n</div>\n</html>]`

Where the values that match in the string are `undefined`.

When I use `.match(re)`, all the matched values are returned as expected:

`['<meta class='a'/>', '<meta class='b'/>']`

Is there a javascript function that can generate the result below?

```
['<html>\n', "<meta class='a'/>", '\n', "<meta class='b'/>", '\n', '<div>\n<p>test</p>\n</div>\n</html>]
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at regex.exec here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: What does `RegExp` expected to match?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you planning to do with the results? Also, where in your HTML are the `stringpart1` and `match1` etc. strings you claim to be getting back?

Comment: You need to supply a snippet of the actual html because it is hard to gather what you want/need when you don't include them BUT you include them in our expected results.

Comment: @jamesemanon made some updates for you

Answer (score 3):

**Edit - my solution was based on the original question before edits. I would revise, but I actually think that after the edits to the question, james emanon's answer is on point and anything I came up with would just be a rehash of what he has.**

Based on the regex you had, it appears that what you're looking to be able to do is pick a particular html tag and search your content for all occurrences of that tag and then output both the beginning and ending tags plus the content into an output array.

Here's one way to accomplish that: [repl.it link](https://repl.it/Dc0p)

```
const text = "<html><div>content</div>><div>content</div></html>";
const tag = "div";
const re = new RegExp("(<"+tag+">)(.*?)(<\/"+tag+">)", "g");
let final = [];

let matches = text.match(re).map((m) => m.replace(/>(.)/, ">@@@$1")
                                         .replace(/\<(?=[^\<]*$)/, "@@@<")
                                         .split("@@@"));

for (let i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<matches[i].length; j++) {
        final.push(matches[i][j]);
    }
}

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 2):

P1xt's solution above is good. For a shorter version, this one "seems" to work - here is a quick work up I did. I am assuming the undefined's correspond to the 'matches' array.

```
var text = "<html>\n<meta class='a'/>\n<meta class='b'/>\n<div>\n<p>test</p>\n</div>\n</html>"
var tag = "meta";
var re = new RegExp("<(\/)?" + tag + ".*?>", "gm")
var matches = text.match(re)

text.split(re).reduce( (p,c) => {
   (!c) ? p.push(matches.shift()) : p.push(c);
   return p;
}, [])
```